# session in asp.net is getting close after 2-3 minutes

Tags: asp.net, session, sessionend

I have made a web application which uses `user authentication` and if user is authenticated user then i store it in `Session` like below.

```
Session("uid") = txtUid.text
```

But after 2-3 minutes `Session` is automatically cleared.

Comment: Check in `IIS` if `Apppool` isn't recycling automatically and what's it's Timeout setting....???

Comment: how to check in IIS that Apppool is recycling or not?

Comment: From `IIS -> application pools -> select pool -> Advanced settings -> section "process model" => Idle Time-out(minutes)`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 - 3 minutes?

it means that you are not sure how long it takes for the session to close.

from here i can assume that you are using internet explorer?

internet explorer has a known issue with asp.net, if you have an underscore in your virtual path like

```
www.mySite.com/some_test_site.aspx
```

so i bet you have a scenario like this.

in any case, you can add the following line to your web.config to keep vars for 60 minutes:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="60"/>
```

it goes under:

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
```

Comment: i am not using internet explorer and in web.config file i don't have any statement like this   `<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="60"/>`

Comment: Yes mate, thats why i said you need to  'add' it  :)

Answer (score 3):

increase your `session` time in `Web.config`

```
 <system.web>
    <sessionState timeout="260"  />
  </system.web>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the session state of your web application in `web.config`. Add this code in the `Configuration` section of your `web.config`.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
  ...
   <sessionState timeout="20" />
  ...
 </system.web>
</configuration>
```